# Angular: How do I transfer my usersearch-input data into another component and create from the search result a list?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angular, typescript

I hope someone can help me, first of all I'm not very good at Angular (first project with it). I'm using Angular 8 for my frontend from the application.

I tried to create a html page(...stuff/searches) where the user can input search criteria to find Stuff. The input from the user should then be transfered into another html page (...stuff/searches/list). There I try to call a method for my backend to run the search in the database and give me back the Stuff that fits the search criteria from the user. The recieved Stuff I want to put into a list. 
My backend works fine with the call (testet with Postman). I tried from another question on this page to export my data to a "service.ts" and get it from there but somehow it does not work.

**stuff-search.component.html**

```
  <div [hidden]="submitted">
    <h1>Stuff Search</h1>
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #stuffForm="ngForm">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description"  [(ngModel)]="model.description" name="description">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="rating">Rating</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="rating" required  [(ngModel)]="model.rating" name="rating">
          <option *ngFor="let rating of ratings" [value]="rating">{{rating}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="birth_date">Birth date</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="birth_date"  [(ngModel)]="model.birthDate" name="birthDate">
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" href="/stuff/searches/list">Search</button>


    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**stuff-search.component.ts**

```
import {StuffService} from '../../service/stuff.service';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {Stuff} from '../../dto/stuff';
import {DataService} from '../../service/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-stuff-search',
  templateUrl: './stuff-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stuff-search.component.scss']
})
export class StuffSearchComponent{

  ratings = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  id: number;
  private sub: any;

  constructor( private stuffService: StuffService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private dataService: DataService) {
  }

  stuff: any;
  submitted = false;
  model = new Stuff('', '', null, '');

  private searchStuff(stuff) {
    this.stuffService.searchStuff(stuff).subscribe(
      (stuffs: Stuff) => {
        this.model = stuffs;
      },
      error => {
        // this.defaultServiceErrorHandling(error);
      }
    );
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.dataService.setData(this.model);
  }

}
```

**stuff-list.component.html**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {StuffService} from '../../service/stuff.service';
import {DataService} from '../../service/data.service';
import {Stuff} from "../../dto/stuff";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-stuff-list',
  templateUrl: './stuff-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stuff-list.component.scss']
})
export class StuffListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private stuffService: StuffService, private dataService: DataService) {
  }
  model = new Stuff('', '', null, '');
  stuffs: any;

  onRefresh() {
    // this.ngOnInit();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
    this.stuffService.searchStuff(this.dataService.getData()).subscribe(stuffs => this.stuffs= stuffs);
  }

  deleteStuff(id, position) {
    console.log('Delete stuff');
    this.stuffService.deleteStuff(id).subscribe(t => this.onRefresh());
  }
}
```

**stuff-list.component.ts**

```
import {StuffService} from '../../service/stuff.service';
import {DataService} from '../../service/data.service';
import {Stuff} from "../../dto/stuff";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-stuff-list',
  templateUrl: './stuff-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stuff-list.component.scss']
})
export class StuffListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private stuffService: StuffService, private dataService: DataService) {
  }
  model = new Stuff('', '', null, '');
  stuffes: any;

  onRefresh() {
    // this.ngOnInit();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
    this.stuffService.searchStuff(this.dataService.getData()).subscribe(stuffes=> this.stuffes= stuffes);
  }

  deletesStuff(id, position) {
    console.log('Delete stuff');
    this.stuffService.deleteStuff(id).subscribe(t => this.onRefresh());
  }
}
```

**data.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Stuff} from '../dto/stuff';


// To Transfer the Data from the UserInput Search (stuff-search) to stuff-list
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  public stuff: Stuff;

  constructor() {
  }

  setData(stuff) {
    this.stuff= stuff;
  }
  getData() {
    return this.stuff;
  }
}
```

Every tip/help would be appreciated. I tried it the whole day. Maybe it is only a little mistake and I cant't find it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use hrefs on links (stuff-search.component.html). Use instead routerLink, or router.navigate method. When you navigate to another page using href, your data will be lost since the app is reinitialized. The trick with single-page apps (which angular is) is that you navigate through it without reloading the page. Probably this is the issue you have.

Please, read this https://angular.io/guide/router#router-links

Also I would suggest to pass to the service not the object, you are working with, but it's cloned copy. This will avoid some unpredictable things that may occur.

`this.dataservice.setData(cloneDepp(this.model))`

cloneDepp is being imported from lodash lib, you have it in the project already

Comment: thanks for the help - it solved the problem. :) I had to change a little bit more in the backend because there was a mistake that popped when I fixed this one.